# In dynamic programming, do I always have to fill the entire table?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

When doing [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), I would usually fill the table eagerly (from bottom to top, instead of using top-down recursion). This results in a nested loop filling in all values in the table.

Do I always have to fill up the entire table?

**Example DP task:**

Calculate the distance between the strings `hello` and `world`:

```
  h e l l o
w 1 2 3 4 5
o 2 2 3 4 5
r 3 3 3 4 5
l 4 4 3 3 4
d 5 5 4 4 4
```

The example above (I hope I did not do an error) compares every substring of `hello` and `world` and stores its difference. E.g. the difference of `he` and `wor` is 3. Further calculations are based on the stored results.

Is it really necessary to compare every substring?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes not. For some DP problems a significant number of states will never be used, so you don't have to compute all of them. One way to take advantage of this is to use [memoization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468). You define a function that computes a DP state. The function first checks if that state has already been computed. If not, it computes that state using recursion. This way only states that are actually used will be computed.

Comment: Okay, so with this approach we go back from bottom-up eager evaluation to a top-down approach. In the end idk how beneficial that is in practice. Could you give a reproducible example of a task where you think that it is better than the bottom-up way? If you like, use  https://godbolt.org/ to provide some ready-to-run code.